# Error in MainActivity.kt file in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I created a project in Android studio.
The code of MainActivity.kt is

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        println("onCreate called")
    }
}
```

In line 4 of above code I was getting error. The **activity_main.xml** is present in a**pp->res->layout**
There is error in **activity_main.xml**. But **MainActivity.kt** is not recognising it and showing error

```
Unresolved reference: activity_main
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Caches and restart

Comment: See my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073064/androidstudio-cannot-find-layout/61074258#61074258

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AndroidStudio Cannot Find Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073064/androidstudio-cannot-find-layout)

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I tried that method already, but I didn't worked for me. So I reinstalled the andriod studio, so then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have imported the correct R file as suggested, and if that doesn't resolve, try to clear the cache files. - File > Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported R file in activity:

```
import com.example.app.R;
```

Comment: Try File > Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

Try importing this:

```
import com.example.app.R;
```

and you can also try to type `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.i("MAIN ACTIVITY", "onCreate called")
       }
    }
```