# Cannot resolve second_activity Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and I was working on moving from one activity to other. Name of other activity is `activity_second`.

The following is the code of the `SecondActivity` Java class.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("com.example.quicklauncher.TextView")){
            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            String text=getIntent().getExtras().getString("com.example.quicklauncher.TextView");
            tv.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Try clean and rebuild the project

Comment: still shows that same error. Fortunately, the app works as intended.

Comment: OK, try file->invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try File-> Invalidate caches/restart

Comment: This answer is identical [to the one you gave here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61074258/2985643). Please vote to close this question as a duplicate rather than just posting the same answer again here.

Comment: Hi, this question is closed @skomisa