# Why activity name is not getting resolved in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I've an activity XML file created under layouts under my package but still it's complains

```
package com.alen.cybercpm;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class comrade_login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comrade_login);
    }
}
```

activity_comrade_login comes in RED/ERROR but I've that file in my package.

I've a splash screen as my Main Activity. then this activity is called.

Comment: Try to import com.alen.cybercpm.R in your class.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Oftentimes, you can simply restart Android Studio and these kinds of problems can be resolved. Or @zinonX 's solution can work quite nicely. Best of luck.

Comment: Have you tried 

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

then

> File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

this resolve for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517380/cannot-resolve-second-activity-android-studio/61517504#61517504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing seems to be wrong with your code, Just Restart you `Android Studio`. You will face such kinds of unexpected and silly problems in future so, the best way is to clear `caches` by Restarting Your `Android Studio`

Answer (score 1):

change your Class `comrade_login` to `ComradeLoginActivity`

Then `clean code`
After this `Rebuild code`
Now `clean chache and restart`

Hope it will help you

Thankew! Happy Coding